# Get reviewer status (guest or verified)

Tags: review

When listing product reviews I need to put a tag close to the reviewer name saying "verified customer" however I do not know ho to retrieve this info from the model.

Reviews are returned using this function:

```
$_items = $this->getReviewsCollection()->getItems();
```

And user info by this:

```
foreach ($_items as $_review):

.....

$_review->getNickname()
```

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on what criteria you are using to determine a 'verified customer' - you can either retrieve the customer model from the Nickname and then check and existing attribute or you can create your own attribute and check that.

I am not allowed to write comments yet so can you provide more info on how you determine what is verified?